# Is there any difference between using/not using "astype(np.float)" for narray?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, user-defined-types, numpy-ndarray

I'm going to import the txt file which contains Numbers only, for some coding practice.

Noticed that i can get the same result with either code_1 or code_2:

```
code_1 = np.array(pd.read_csv('e:/data.txt', sep='\t', header=None)).astype(np.float)

code_2 = np.array(pd.read_csv('e:/data.txt', sep='\t', header=None))
```

So I wonder if there is any difference between using or not using `.astype(np.float)`? 
please tell me if there is an similar question. thx a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataFrame.astype()` method is used to cast a pandas object to a specified `dtype`. `astype()` function also provides the capability to convert any suitable existing column to categorical type.

The `DataFrame.astype()` function comes very handy when we want to case a particular column data type to another data type.

In your case, the file is loaded as a `DataFrame`. The numbers will be loaded as integers or floats depending on the numbers. The `astype(np.float)` method converts the numbers to floats. On the other hand if the numbers are already of float type, then as you saw there will not be any difference between the two.

Comment: thx bg2094. Don't you think `np.array()` is applied to DataFrame first, then `.astype(np.float)`?

Comment: Except in this case it's np.array(DataFrame).astype(), function of ndarray, but the effect is the same. Also I dont remember which np.float defaults to, but I believe there're 32 and 64 bit varieties, so there might be that difference too.

Comment: Yes as @IcedLance mentioned, the effect is still the same. By default np.float defaults to 64. Python floats are by default 64 too.